# After log out I cannot disable my laptop touchpad

Tags: touchpad

I have Lenovo Z580 with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Usually both in Windows 7 or Ubuntu I can just press FN + F6 to disable touchpad. However, for Ubuntu afterI logged out the operating system and then logged back in pressing FN + F6 button does nothing.

How can I disable my touchpad without restarting my computer?